# How can I get an index value from A to Z using data-ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been using before the index value like this:

```
{{ $index }}
```

What I really need is instead of getting a number I would like to get an uppercase character going from A to Z.  There should be no problem of running out of characters as I have at the most only 10 things that are repeated.

Can someone tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following method to your scope:

```
$scope.indexChar = function (index) {
    return String.fromCharCode(65 + index);
};
```

Then use it in your view:

```
{{ indexChar($index) }}
```

---

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xs5Qn/

Comment: that solution is more smoother than mine

Answer (score 3):

You could use the function String.fromCharCode(n), wrapped in a filter:

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('fromCharCode', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return String.fromCharCode(input);
  };
});
```

In the template you can call it like this:

```
{{($index + 65) | fromCharCode}}  // 65 is the letter A
```

Edit: you could also create a more specific filter that returns only uppercase letters:

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('letterFromCode', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var code = input % 26;
    return String.fromCharCode(65 + code);
  };
});
```

Comment: Why not just move `+ 65` to the filter?

Comment: I suppose it could be done, but it would need a different name. Right now it's transparent.
See the edit above

Comment: +1 Thx for the edit. Filter is more reusable than a function in the scope.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an array, what represent the alphabet.

```
$scope.alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", .... "Z"];
```

and use it in the Template like:

```
{{ alphabet[$index] }}
```